# how to publish two different asp.net web application into singe website using IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am new to IIS server. I have **two different asp.net web application** project example client project and admin project. when i try to publish this two application **seperatly** configured working fine.

but I need

**client project ---> localhost:9999 or www.test.com**

**admin project ---> localhost:9999/admin or www.test.com/admin**

if it's possible mean please tell step by step

Comment: Try and get back with a more specific question please. Asking for step-by-step tutorials is off-topic here. You should use a search engine for that purpose.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called "virtual applications". I suggest you look that up.

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to create a website and create binding

```
  <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9999:" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.test.com" />
                </bindings>
```

2.You need to register www.test.com in hosts files
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Or you need to register it to DNS.

127.0.0.1    www.test.com

3.Create a virtual application under your website with name **admin**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/

4.Publish your client project to the root folder of your website

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2019

5.Publish your admin project to the application **localhost/admin**.

6.Grant permission for your application pool identity(IIS Apppool\apppoolname) and authenticated user like IUSR.

7.Try to access the applications.

Since virtual application are isolated from your root application, you don't have to afraid of application conflicts.

Comment: What i'm tried. added client project in iis and it's working fine **localhost:9090** on browser and when i trying to add admin project **(virtual directories)** and click on browse **localhost:9090/admin** the start up page that is login page show when i click on login the next page that is main page showing error**localhost:9090/main**  **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** if i change the url manually like **localhost:9090/admin/main** works fine could please help me out this

Comment: is that any problem with using global.asax

Comment: @JeenathKumar Thats why I request you to host admin as virtual application instead of virtual directory. If you host your application in a virtual directory, the index for /admin would stop working because admin will not consider /admin folder as the root folder. If you host admin as an application, then the root client project will be isolated and admin will work as a independent application.

Comment: i have successfully created virtual application and it run login page **localhost:9090/admin** that is no issue when the use click login the url automactically removed and the url like **localhost:9090/main** but i try to put manually admin before the /main that is **localhost:9090/admin/main** it's working every time i put this manually is not possible. any other alternate or is that any problem with using global.asax why because i am using route table it rewrite the url   **thanks for helping me**